# Identify online user in weemo video call application

Tags: javascript, video, cloud, conference, sightcall

I am working on Weemo JS API for video conference.

1) I need some technical help for identify online user for conference. 
2) How can i pass data from caller to callee? 
3) How online user can disconnected from cloud?

please provide some technical ref for same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can know if a user is online or not by using the `weemo.getStatus('USER_UID')` method.

- (void) getStatus('USER_UID')

When 'USER_UID' is the value of the target user Uid (String).

You will need to use the `weemo.onGetHandler(name, obj)` callback to catch the answer.

Here is an example of how to get the status of a user with a 'USER_ID' equal to 'userTestStatus':

```
var weemo = new Weemo('AppId', 'Token', 'Type');

weemo.onGetHandler = function(name, obj) {
    switch(name) {
        case 'status':
            var uid = obj.uid;
            if(obj.value == 0) {
                console.log("User "+uid+" is offline with a status "+obj.value);
            } else {
                console.log("User "+uid+" is online with a status "+obj.value);
            }
        break;
    }
};


weemo.onConnectionHandler = function(message, code) {
    console.log("Connection Handler : " + message + ' ' + code);
    switch(message) {
        case 'sipOk':
            weemo.getStatus('userTestStatus');
        break;
    }
};

weemo.initialize();
```

FYI: In this example I used the getStatus in the onConnectionHandler after receiving a "sipOk" because I want to make sure that my user is completly connected before runing a getStatus. Once you user is connected to the Weemo Cloud you can execute a getStatus out of the onConnectionHandler.

Once connected you can disconnect your user by using the `weemo.reset()` method. This will disconnect your user from the Weemo cloud.

- (void) reset()

*The reset function is used in order to properly disconnect the user from the cloud, and be able to connect to the real-time platform with other credentials.*

You can find more details in the documentation and sample code available on the Weemo github [here](https://github.com/weemo/Weemo.js).

You can also find the full Weemo JavaScript API [here](http://docs.weemo.com/release/5.1/js/interface_weemo.html)